# Is it permitted to call the police on Shabbos if you come across a dead person?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, funeral-burial-levaya

Violating the Shabbos in a case a life threatening situation is a mitzvah (Yoma 84)

However what if one comes across a dead person on Shabbos. Normally one would report this to the police. However on Shabbos where the person is already dead. May one call the police and notify them?

Comment: What pikuach nefesh exists to permit breaking shabbat?

Comment: Would one suspect there is a murderer on the run looking to murder other people? Or is it natural death

Comment: @mbloch I don't know that's a good question

Comment: Isn't there a Biblical prohibition to leave the deceased unburied?

Comment: @Lee you don't call the police to bury the body.

Comment: Depending on how dead he is, it's worth calling an ambulance!

Comment: @Lee Not if it's not a Jew?

Comment: @SAH that's not entirely obvious, at least in Israel. cf Yehoshua and the 5 Kings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is not about the body - the police do not resurrect (as of now), but about its condition and the consequences of the discovery:

1. First, if the body looks fresh and recent - you must call the ambulance first, as the person might be not as much dead as you think!
2. If it's fresh there might be a following Pikuach Nefesh danger for others (think of a serial killer) or for you to be found near the body (if the killer is near). In this case, you must call the police.
3. If the body is old and there's no reason to believe that an immediate danger emerges for you, for the body or for others, there's no permission to break Shabbat.

---

PS on #2: I came across (what looked to me like) a dead homeless person some 12 years ago in Jerusalem, and I ran to a secular guy to use his phone to call an ambulance. Turned out he passed out and it saved his life!

Comment: What does a downvote mean - you don't agree with my reasoning? We should stop letting people downvote without commenting!

Comment: I haven't downvoted. However I think, "My common sense" doesn't count as a valid source. B"H you were zoche to save someone's life.

Comment: Why should we downvote this? IMHO 1. The answer submitted his own common sense as a source, obviously based on his own understanding of Torah/Halachah. So? 2. The OP declared: "Violating the Shabbos in a case [of] a life threatening situation, is a mitzvah....HOWEVER". An answer should not be required to be smarter than the OP usually. The OP gave as a "given" that finding a body is not pikuach nefesh. The answer objected and showed how it could be in fact life saving (at least out of doubt). 3. non sourced answers should only be downvoted if you disagree or have proof against it.

Comment: @user218076 If common sense works for Rambam or Meiri or Chofetz Chaim, I don't see a reason it won't work for others. After all "אל תסתכל בקנקן".

Comment: @DavidKenner My answer shows only **applications** of the current accepted Halachahs. The first step is to sort things out - that's exactly what I do. 2. I didn't understand it. 3. I completely agree.

Comment: I was just explaining why someone might have downvoted. The Rishonim didn't use common sense, they used Daas Torah. The current edited answer is better.

Comment: @user218076 Of course if you're a Rishon it's Daas Torah, but they called it עניות דעתי.

Comment: @David You just said one could downvote if they disagree and you also ask why should we downvote. Clearly someone disagrees. This shouldn't be perplexing or unexpected

Comment: I downvoted. Regarding #1; if the body is fresh, and there is even the slightest sign of hope, one must call(and not just because it's fresh). Re: #2; to call the police on shabbat when seeing a body, there has to be *some* sign of foul play. Just because it's fresh, doesn't mean there's a serial killer around. Just plain wrong...And #3; if it is old, there is some leniency with shabbat(not like you wrote).

Comment: @chachamNisan I didn't understand #1 - *one must call* - call who? #2 the only reason for breaking Shabbos is an immediate threat (PN). A serial killer is an example of an immediate danger. What's wrong here? #3 elaborate please.

Comment: #1 an ambulance or someone that could save the person. #2 you have to have some sign that this was a murder....just because a person is dead doesn't mean he was murdered. #3 if you don't know what leniency there is, then you shouldn't have answered.

Comment: @DoubleAA I commented after user218076 who pointed out that his common sense was not a valid source. I asked why because I suspected people were downvoting just because he didn't source it. Yes, I guess one could disagree (as we are seeing) but it didn't feel like something so extremely disagreeable at the time. :)